# Unity prevent clicking for 1s

Tags: c#

I have a Unity Slidepuzzle-game(4x4) and i check where the open field is to move. I tried to make a slide animation with MoveTowards and that worked but now i have the problem that when i click two pieces (fast) that are next to the open space, both will move into it because the piece isnt fully there so the ray cant hit anything. P.S: it works without the animation but i just dont want the pieces to just teleport. i want a smooth slide.

i tried solving it with a boolean so that when i click it moving is set to true and when the animation finished set to false again but that didnt work.

```
void MovePuzzle()
    {
        float duration = 0.5f;

        if(go_left)
        {
            Vector3 endPos1 = new Vector3(transform.position.x - move_amount.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(endPos1, duration));
            go_left = false;
            moved = true;
        }
        if (go_right)
        {
            Vector3 endPos2 = new Vector3(transform.position.x + move_amount.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(endPos2, duration));
            go_right = false;
            moved = true;
        }
        if (go_up)
        {
            Vector3 endPos3 = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + move_amount.y, transform.position.z);
            StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(endPos3, duration));
            go_up = false;
            moved = true;
        }
        if (go_down)
        {
            Vector3 endPos4 = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - move_amount.y, transform.position.z);
            StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(endPos4, duration)); 
            go_down = false;
            moved = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveTowards(Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time);

            Debug.Log(counter + " / " + duration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to restrict clicks until the slide animation is finished?
Im relativly new to Unity so dont expect to much knowledge from me :D.

Comment: I take it the provided code is for a behaviour on each piece of the puzzle. Is there an additional behaviour for the overall game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you tried it with a boolean and it didn't work. I think if it's done correctly, it should work.

In the first line of MovePuzzle(), write:

```
if (moved)
{
    return;
}
```

Then, after the while block (so outside of it), write:

```
moved = false;
```

And you should probably rename it to isMoving then.

Comment: ye this works too, but i just shortened the animation time and i think it's better like that, but thanks anyway!